# XAML ListView How to style

Tags: wpf, xaml

An image is better than a thousand of words.

[image]

I have a list view Left image, and want to force my inner object (TextBlock) to use the full space of my ListViewItem, Right image.

How can i do to style it?

Here is my xaml

```
    <ListView
        x:Name="ListProperties"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ImportarConfig.PropertiesList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=ListProperties.Width}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsOptional}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName}" Style="{StaticResource BlockHeaderWarning}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="TextBlock_Drop" Width="{Binding ElementName=ListProperties.Width}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I tryed Changing Grid to Stackpanel but nothing happens

Comment: Picture's great, but can you give us your XAML as well?

Comment: Yep.. XAML allowed mow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ItemContainerStyle` and set your `HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Something like:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="ListProperties"
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ImportarConfig.PropertiesList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=ListProperties.Width}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsOptional}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName}" Style="{StaticResource BlockHeaderWarning}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="TextBlock_Drop" Width="{Binding ElementName=ListProperties.Width}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```